# Выделить датафрейм по временному промежутку

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть датафрейм из многих дней. Как сделать, чтобы весь дф был скажем с 14:00 до 19:00 каждого дня?

Пример:

```
3/9/2017    7:21:00     138.55
3/9/2017    7:18:00     138.68
3/9/2017    7:15:00     138.65
3/9/2017    7:11:00     138.68
3/9/2017    7:07:00     138.61
3/9/2017    7:06:00     138.65
3/9/2017    7:01:00     138.7
3/9/2017    6:51:00     138.59
3/9/2017    6:49:00     138.7
3/9/2017    6:36:00     138.57
3/9/2017    6:32:00     138.7
3/9/2017    6:10:00     138.71
3/9/2017    5:18:00     139.03
3/9/2017    5:17:00     139.05
3/9/2017    4:17:00     139.31
3/9/2017    4:04:00     139.24
3/8/2017    19:56:00    139.04
3/8/2017    19:52:00    139.09
3/8/2017    19:36:00    139
3/8/2017    19:34:00    139.04
3/8/2017    19:33:00    139.02
3/8/2017    19:29:00    139.02
3/8/2017    19:05:00    139.04
3/8/2017    18:57:00    139.04
3/8/2017    18:35:00    139.04
3/8/2017    18:30:00    139.01
3/8/2017    18:13:00    139
3/8/2017    18:08:00    139
3/8/2017    17:43:00    138.91
3/8/2017    17:41:00    138.92
3/8/2017    17:31:00    139
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

Исходный DF (последние 3 строки):

```
In [51]: df.tail(3)
Out[51]:
        Date      Time     Val
28  3/8/2017  17:43:00  138.91
29  3/8/2017  17:41:00  138.92
30  3/8/2017  17:31:00  139.00
```

решение:

```
res = (df
       .reset_index()
       .set_index(pd.to_datetime(df["Date"] + " " + df["Time"]))
       .between_time("14:00", "19:00")
       .set_index("index"))
```

результат:

```
In [65]: res
Out[65]:
           Date      Time     Val
index
23     3/8/2017  18:57:00  139.04
24     3/8/2017  18:35:00  139.04
25     3/8/2017  18:30:00  139.01
26     3/8/2017  18:13:00  139.00
27     3/8/2017  18:08:00  139.00
28     3/8/2017  17:43:00  138.91
29     3/8/2017  17:41:00  138.92
30     3/8/2017  17:31:00  139.00
```

Comment: надо бы минуты еще - 19:56 - это уже не "до 19:00", либо до 18 сделать dt.hour

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо, исправил...