# Выделить период с заданным промежутком времени

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, фильтрация

Есть DataFrame, в нем минутные строки с начала дня.

Как выделить период который я хочу, например с 13:00 до 18:00?

```py
df = pd.read_csv('200524.csv')
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Num']
```

Comment: можете привести небольшой пример данных? Ответ будет зависеть от формата даты и времени...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: а вы пробовали пользоваться поиском? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125539/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83/1125559#comment1945521_1125559

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выделить датафрейм по временному промежутку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125539/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

с такими данными как у вас минуты скорее всего прочитаются как целое число, поэтому и фильтровать нужно соответсвенно:

```
In [111]: df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\200524.csv")

In [112]: df.dtypes
Out[112]:
<DATE>    int64
<TIME>    int64
<Num>     int64
dtype: object

In [113]: res = df.query("180000 <= `<TIME>` < 190000")

In [114]: res
Out[114]:
         <DATE>  <TIME>  <Num>
420    20200401  180000      7
421    20200401  180100      1
422    20200401  180300     43
423    20200401  180400      4
424    20200401  180500     10
...         ...     ...    ...
17349  20200430  184100    227
17350  20200430  184200    162
17351  20200430  184300    358
17352  20200430  184400     57
17353  20200430  184500    332

[1010 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: @Николай, а причем здесь `Dis` - его в вашем файле нет

Comment: @Николай, я вам уже говорил - решение зависит от формата и качества данных. Если хотите рабочие и прверенные ответы - приводите __воспроизводимые__ примеры данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: @Николай, просто укажите в `.query()` правильное имя столбца после переименования - `df.query("180000 <= Time < 190000")`

Answer (score 0):

Решение аналогичного вопроса:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates

Comment: да, верно подметили

Comment: Если вы даете в качестве ответа _голую_ ссылку, то лучше оформлять ее в виде комментария.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: принято, коллеги, спасибо